# How to handle design system in micro-frontends?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

In the micro-frontend every application would be running separately, in that case, each one of the applications will be having its own CSS.

Let's assume we are taking MUI as the UI library. So each application that uses MUI will be having its own theme provider.

Now the stakeholder wants to change the button's color from blue to black, in this scenario I have to manually go and change the color to each one of the applications separately.

Do we have to do like this only or any other pattern is available in Micro-Frontend to solve this Design System issue?

Please help me with your suggestions !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a theming `package` for your micro-frontend `apps`. This package provides a [theme object](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/#explore) for Mui [ThemeProvider](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-provider). It can have some default theme properties and some additional (editable) properties which from an API.

Then you need a portal where your client or stakeholder can edit the theme, from some theme editor app. Basically, that will `UPDATE` your theme object (database).

Your package will `GET` those changes and update all your micro-frontend apps. I have seen a similar kind of implementation in a [Turborepo](https://turbo.build/) app.

Comment: You are saying something like a component library, where we can have all the UI elements needed for our application. And install it as an npm package to get those. Am i right here ?

Comment: And this component library will handle the palette theme object which will then passed to the ThemeProvider.

This will work but what happens if I want to change the style of the button like reducing the padding/margin/etc.. This time I need to reinstall the updated library everytimes to get the new change in all the apps

Comment: In this case, you can create an API which provides you theme object. 
But you can do a GET call on your app load and set the response (theme object) to the ThemeProvider